# Shell commands in Tcl

Tags: shell, module, command, tcl, exec

The question I'd like to ask is general.
I'm trying to load this module writing it in a tcl script

```
set module_installer "installer_mod/2019"
module load $module_installer
```

It gives

> ```
> invalid command name "module" while executing
> ```

How can I write, to include shell commands in tcl, I have also tried exec command.

Comment: As I understand it, modules can only be loaded in Unix shells, not Tcl scripts.

Comment: You might be looking for [load](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/load.htm) or [source](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/source.htm). Not sure what shell has to do with tcl libraries, though.

Comment: Do you have to load the module *before* you launch Tcl?

Comment: No,I want to load modules concurrently

Comment: Some tips for getting some answers: What does your attempt using exec look like? What are the shell commands you are trying to run? When answering on a comment type '@' followed by the user name of the recipient. Otherwise they have no idea this post is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `source` to load modules since they are contained in a single file not requiring other files.

```
source $module_installer
```

Then you can call variables and/or `proc`s from the loaded module.